# Angular CLI doesn't detect NPM version during ng update (v10 --> v11)

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

I am trying to update my angular app (v10) to match the global version of the @angular/cli I have installed on dev machine (v11).  (seems like a better idea than just suppressing the warnings)

However ng update fails, stating I need NPM version 6 (I have reviewed info at the link in error message).  Trouble is **I am on npm version 6.14.8** already.  Also, the error message looks like it should show the detected npm version, but is suspiciously empty.

**Running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS**

**ng update @angular/core @angular/cli (error message)**
[image]

**npm --version**

6.14.8

**ng --version (project folder)**
[image]

I did not find any similar questions in my searching.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed nodejs with snap? I have installed it with snap and then deleted it and installed it with the official repository. After that, all things are perfectly working

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I am abit confused though, as I am already running 6.14.8 as my global version of npm.  My concern is that the npm version is not being detected at all by angular cli (see the screenshot of error message).  With this in mind do you still feel that your solution would resolve the issue?  and if yes, would you be kind enough to help me understand how?

Comment: Thank you! it was installed with snap and re-installing from official repo solved the issue.  If you would like to change the comment to an answer I will happily "accept" it.  Either way, thank you for your help.